# Preventing Duplicates in a large SQL Server table most effectively

Tags: sql-server, optimization

What would be the most efficient way of preventing insertion of duplicate rows in a SQL table that may contain up to 500 million rows?

I see two ways:

1) Create composite primary key on columns that define duplicate record and catch the DuplicateKey exceptions.

2) use `IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE [MyCondition])`, but this will require indexing those columns that participate in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY.  The duplication check will be done on the insert.

If you are using SSIS, match lookup on the key and direct the duplicates to a hospital table.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT UC_MyConstraintName UNIQUE (col1,col2,col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) is faster than 2) as you are just replicating what SQL Server does with machine code using compiled sql code.

For something a little out of the box: If insert performance is more critical than immediate correctness then ignore the duplicates... at first.

You could flag or separately log unchecked rows and run a scheduled task to go back and recheck them. This might be OK for a very slow read option, or where the duplicates aren't too much of a problem.

If you don't need the write to fail straight away on the duplicate you could use service broker to do the duplicate checks asynchronously this will take a bit of work, but start [here](http://rusanu.com/2006/10/16/writing-service-broker-procedures/) for a a primer.